# Android - Communication between two Fragments via a shared ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have a `Fragment A` that displays a list of items. When one item is clicked we navigate to a `Fragment B` that shows a more detailed view on the selected item. So, I needed some sort of communication between `Fragment A` & `B`.

In the docs (see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) ) they state that a shared `ViewModel` for communication between Fragments is the recommended way. So, implement it like this:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // used to share Item between list and detail view
    private val _selectedItem = MutableLiveData<Item>()
    
    // Fragment B listens for this LiveData variable
    val selectedItem : LiveData<Item> = _selectedItem
    
    // called by the Fragment A which passes the selected item as argument
    fun selectItem(item: Item) {
        _selectedItem.value = item
    }
}
```

In `Fragment B`, we listen for the `selectedItem` LiveData variable like this:

```
....
// I use a global variable here cuz I want to use it in several different methods
private lateinit var selectedItem : Item
....
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // listen for the selected item
    sharedViewModel.selectedItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { item ->
        selectedItem = item
    })
}
```

Now, in `onStart()` I have some operations that can only operate when `selectedItem` is initialized:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    
    doSomethingWithSelectedItem(selectedItem) //<--- CRASH
    doAnotherThingWithSelectedItem(selectedItem)  // probably it would crash here, too 
}
```

At this point, I get the exception that the `selectedItem` lateinit var variable is not initialized. So, I assume that at this point the setting in `onViewCreated()` (which is `selectedItem = item`) is not kicked in, yet.

So, my question is: **Which lifecycle method is the best when you want to initialize a lateinit variable whose value is shared via a ViewModel between two Fragments ?**

Comment: Why would you have a lateinit reference in the first place? My advice would be to move `doAnotherThingWithSelectedItem` to the Observer and remove variable `item`

Comment: You do the operations you want to do on the observe, not onStart. you dont even need a global var, much less lateinit, if you simply pass the data to those methods when you receive it on observe

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the function inside the observe() method of LiveData is not executed instantly. OnViewCreated() is a method that is executed previously to onStart(). If the LiveData observe() method executed the function instantly you wouldn't have any problem.
What the observe() method does is to set the LiveData object to observe to a change to its value without executing the defined function instantly.

What I would do is writting this piece of code in `Fragment B`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    selectedItem = sharedViewModel.selectedItem.value
}
```

In your case I think that you don't even need to use a LiveData object because you only want to get a value and this value won't change as long as you are in the same fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> onStart() lifecycle of the fragment is called prior to the onViewCreated()
> lifecycle of the fragment.
>
> observe the livedata in onstart and set the lateinit variable. And depends on what ur function do, u can call them in onStart() after lateinit variable is set or in onViewCreated()